# CSS Changing Image and Text Based on Click

Tags: css

I'd like to have a SCROLLING IMAGE GALLERY where when you click a GALLERY IMAGE the MAIN image changes as well as the TEXT that accompanies it changes. I'm new at CSS and I don't know jQuery. If I can get a direction on how to accomplish this I'd appreciate it. If this is an inappropriate question, sorry. If so please point me to where I can get help.

(I tried to post an image of what I'm describing but SO won't let me)

Comment: This is not a problem CSS was intended to solve. You should look into JavaScript (you might find a jQUery plugin that does exactly what you want).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use an external jquery plugin.
[Pikachoose](http://www.pikachoose.com/) is just awesome!

Look at a demo for you [http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/p1r7vx0g/1/.](http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/p1r7vx0g/1/)

To initialize it:

```
$(document).ready(
            function (){
                $("#pikame").PikaChoose();
            });
```